# how to impose syntactic constraints in apriori in weka

Tags: constraints, weka, apriori

there is a way to insert syntactic constraints in weka algorithm priori?

For example, I be interested only in rules that have a specific item *I(x)* appearing in the consequent, or rules that have a specific item *I(y)* appearing in the antecedent, or combinations of the above constraints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mine rules with a specific item "I" (what I(x) means in your notation?) appearing in the consequent. For this you need to set the corresponding column "I" as "class variable", that is to make it the last column (with Weka API). Then set "car" to True in the "Apriori" parameters (see the picture below) and, possibly, don't forget to lower the "minMetric" so that you have nonzero number of rules

[image: Weka-apriori-car-minMetric]