# Weka Apriori RHS

Tags: weka, apriori, market-basket-analysis

I am mining the associate rules using **Apriori** algorithm on the [Titanic dataset](http://www.rdatamining.com/data) using Weka v3.6. The 10 best rules are created as follows:

`1. Class=Crew 885 ==> Sex=Male Age=Adult 862    conf:(0.97) < lift:(1.29)
2. Sex=Male Age=Adult 1667 ==> Class=Crew 862    conf:(0.52) < lift:(1.29)
3. Class=Crew 885 ==> Sex=Male 862    conf:(0.97) < lift:(1.24)
4. Sex=Male 1731 ==> Class=Crew 862    conf:(0.5) < lift:(1.24)
5. Sex=Male 1731 ==> Class=Crew Age=Adult 862    conf:(0.5) < lift:(1.24)
6. Class=Crew Age=Adult 885 ==> Sex=Male 862    conf:(0.97) < lift:(1.24)
7. Sex=Male Age=Adult 1667 ==> Survived=No 1329    conf:(0.8) < lift:(1.18)
8. Survived=No 1490 ==> Sex=Male Age=Adult 1329    conf:(0.89) < lift:(1.18)
9. Sex=Male 1731 ==> Age=Adult Survived=No 1329    conf:(0.77) < lift:(1.18)
10. Age=Adult Survived=No 1438 ==> Sex=Male 1329    conf:(0.92) < lift:(1.18)`

However, I wish to restrict the rules with RHS containing `Survived: "No","Yes"`only. I know in **R**, RHS can be realized by 
[APappearance-class](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/library/arules/html/APappearance-class.html). Is is possible to achieve the similar functionality in Weka?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32759339/how-to-impose-syntactic-constraints-in-apriori-in-weka/32774830#32774830). Briefly: you need to set "car" to True in the "Apriori" parameters

Comment: @lanenok Thank you for the pointer. Is it also possible to specify an item in the consequent for FPGrowth?